# Is it possible to make a user that can only log in using su?

Tags: users, login, authentication, openbsd

I want to make a user that can only be accessed using `su`.

I can see in the `login.conf` man page there are different authentication [types](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.8/login.conf#AUTHENTICATION), and one of the example types is `su`, but I am unable to discover where I might be able to limit a specific user to only log in using one type of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, having a "`*`" in the password field in `/etc/shadow` would work. Be sure to look up manually editing that file, because you might need to fix SELinux context, etc.

Edit:
You can make the password something nobody will ever know. Then the user cannot log in, but only switch it with `sudo`:

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=64 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}{print $1}' | passwd user
```

Comment: My OpenBSD install doesn't have `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Sorry, missed the OpenBSD part - [this resource](https://www.rexconsulting.net/who-did-what-why-all-you-need-is-sudo-passwordless-accounts-even-for-root-html/) says you should be able to set it _somehow_.

Comment: It's not clear to me that I'm looking for a NO-password account, which the article describes as one that cannot gain "UNIX execution access". I am looking to create a user that has full permissions, including adding it to the `wheel` group. I just want to limit authentication type to `su`, assuming I'm understanding authentication and authentication types correctly.

Comment: A user with no (valid) password _cannot_ be logged into directly (console, tty, ssh, etc). The _only_ way to switch to that user would be `sudo su - username` .

Comment: I am not looking to create a user without a valid password.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the revised solution means I will not be able to invoke `doas` without configuring `doas.conf` with `nopass`, which is not a solution for me. So far, the best solution seems like it would be to figure how to limit authentication types.